# How to display distinct values on combox in gxt?

Tags: gxt

I want to display distinct values on combox. I am getting the values stores

```
Group    Number

A           1
B           2
C           1
D           3
E           2
```

I want to display the Number 1,2,3. But now im getting 1,2,1,3,2. How resolve it.

Here is my code:

```
 ListStore<StringFieldModel> store = new ListStore<StringFieldModel>();
        public ComboBox<StringFieldModel> combo= new ComboBox<StringFieldModel>();
        combo.setMinChars(1);
        combo.setFieldLabel(ZingTrack.getUICaptions().Vehicle());
        combo.setDisplayField("name");
        combo.setStore(store);
        combo.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
        combo.setEmptyText(ZingTrack.getUICaptions().Vehicle());
        combo.setLoadingText("Searching...");
        combo.setTypeAhead(true);
        combo.setSelectOnFocus(true);
        combo.setEditable(false);
        combo.setHideTrigger(false);
        combo.setWidth(150);## Heading ##
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a ModelComparer on the store, or just filter the data upon adding it to the store.

Answer (score 0):

For example;

Maybe you apply with this;
**But object's compared attribute must be "Number" column. Your Group-Number Class may be override equals method to compare on Number column**

```
Set<StringFieldModel> set = new HashSet<StringFieldModel>();  
set.addAll(store.getModels());  
StringFieldModel[] modelArray=new StringFieldModel[set.toArray().length];  
store.removeAll();
store.add(Arrays.asList(set.toArray(modelArray)));
```

As you see Set not include duplicate values.